# Создание колоды из двух Enum

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, enum

Я хочу создать колоду карт используя два Enum

```
public enum Suit
{
    Spades = 1,
    Hearts = 2,
    Diamonds = 3,
    Clubs = 4
};
public enum CardNumber
{
    Ace = 11,
    King = 10,
    Queen = 10,
    Jack = 10,
    Ten = 10,
    Nine = 9,
    Eight = 8,
    Seven = 7,
    Six = 6,
    Five = 5,
    Four = 4,
    Three = 3,
    Two = 2,
};
```

Пробую через цикл заполнить колоду карт

```
foreach (Suit suit in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Suit)).ToString())
{
    foreach (CardNumber cardNumber in Enum.GetNames(typeof(CardNumber)).ToString())
    {
        cards.Add (new Card(){ Suit=(suit),CardNumber=(cardNumber)});
        Console.WriteLine(cards.ToString());
    }
}
```

но на выходе получаю это

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BlackJack.Card]
```

кто знает в чем проблема и как ее решить ?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что у списка есть перегрузка метода ToString()?

Comment: А в чём проблема? Вы получаете то, что запросили.

Comment: хорошо я убрал Сonsole.WriteLine(cards.ToString());  написал отдельный цикл который выводит элементы моего списка, выводит BlackJack.Card , что я делаю не так ? как мне добиться желаемого результата ?

Comment: `Ace=14, King=13, Queen=12, Jack=11` наверное всё таки

Comment: Переопределите toString для своего класса Card

Comment: я бы все таки итерировал getvalues, а одинаковые значения в енуме это, имхо, стремно

Comment: я сначала пробовал через GetValues,оно выходит тоже самое ,а одинаковые значения это условие задания

Comment: @Simon: Зависит от того, какой у вас желаемый результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public enum Suit
{
    Spades = 1,
    Hearts = 2,
    Diamonds = 3,
    Clubs = 4
}
public enum CardNumber
{
    Ace = 11,
    King = 10,
    Queen = 10,
    Jack = 10,
    Ten = 10,
    Nine = 9,
    Eight = 8,
    Seven = 7,
    Six = 6,
    Five = 5,
    Four = 4,
    Three = 3,
    Two = 2
}

internal class Card
{
    public string Suit;
    public string CardNumber;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Suit}:{CardNumber}";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cards = new List<Card>(52);
        foreach (var suitName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Suit)))
        {
            foreach (var cardNumber in Enum.GetNames(typeof(CardNumber)))
            {
                cards.Add(new Card
                {
                    Suit = suitName,
                    CardNumber = cardNumber
                });
            }
        }
        cards.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо ,это оно

Comment: я бы на самом деле хранил значения в Enum.

Comment: @temiklis, согласен с Вами. Увидел в вопросе, что в класс пихаются строки, поэтому сделал поля строковыми. Внес соответствующие поправки.

Comment: В таком случае наверное Jack, Queen, King не должны добавиться в коллекцию

Comment: @user5470440 хотя я так посмотрел, у него значений одинаковые для некоторых элементов, и при конверте обратно в Enum значения  King = 10, Queen = 10, Jack = 10,   становятся в Ten. Так что вы были правы, строковые переменные лучший выход здесь, извиняюсь.

Comment: @yolosora, в случае использовая var и GetValues тип переменной suit будет object. Если явно указать тип переменной suit при создании явно, кастовать не потребуется

Comment: @user5470440 да, проглядел что там var стоит